# Detect stream in data load editor in Qlik Sense

Tags: qliksense

Is it possible to get stream related information in data load editor in Qlik Sense App? I cannot create new apps. I can access other information like app id, app path etc.

Answer (score 0):

The stream that an application is published in, to the best if my knowledge, is not available by a System function within the load script. You can certainly pull that information from the Repository API inline. The obvious candidate for doing so would be the `monitor_apps_REST_app` data connection which should be present on your system. You should be able to pass the combination of `DocumentName()` as a variablized WHERE clause into the REST connection pull and then store the stream name or ID.

What is the ultimate use case?

Comment: Thanks Levi. I have multiple streams in multiple environments. Each stream has 3-4 apps which is same in all streams in all environments. So to point to QVD I always have to hard code the path. With stream name and ComputerName () combination I can check environment and stream combination and write if else conditions for the path which I will not have to change for any environment. Sorry if it sounds confusing.

Comment: Would I be able to use the repository API in data load editor?

Comment: You can certainly use the Qlik REST connector to make the requisite API calls, yes.